# Custom multiple div appends in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I hope you can get me out of my current predicament which involves coding style when it comes to appending many elements in a pretty flexible and typesafe way.

Now I see my code below and I feel that it can be written in a more compact and shorter manner, especially in my set function. Also, I'm not sure if I should merge the arrays and keep it in one line.

What makes me wonder most however, is how to append all those divs to a document fragment before placing them to the real DOM as it is fairly complex.

Would you say I'm right about the possible improvements that can be made? If so, then how can I improve it?

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/testopia/ww85a0c9/1/)

```
var superContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('superContainer');
    var article = document.getElementsByTagName('article');
    var obj = {};

    var wrappers = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

    var a1 = ['fruits', 'meat', 'milk', 'soup', 'sweets'];
    var a2 = ['troll', 'gollum', 'imp', 'ork', 'dolly'];
    var a3 = ['foobar'];

    var misc = ['boring', 'fun', 'annoying', 'great'];

    function Constructor() {
        function set() {
            for(var i = 0; i < article.length; i++) {
                var tempSC = document.createElement('div');

                tempSC.appendChild(article[i].parentNode.replaceChild(tempSC, article[i]));
                tempSC.className = 'superContainer';

                create(superContainer[i], wrappers, 0, 0);
                create(obj.a[i], a1, 0, 0);
                create(obj.b[i], a2, 0, 0);
                create(obj.c[i], a3, 0, 0);
                create(obj.milk[i], misc, 1, 2);
                create(obj.sweets[i], misc, 0, 1);
                create(obj.milk[i].children[0], misc, 3, 0);
                create(obj.sweets[i].children[1], misc, 3, 0);
            }
        }

        set();

        function create(parent, elem, loopStart, loopEnd) {
            for(var i = loopStart; i < elem.length - loopEnd; i++) {
                var result = document.createElement('div');
                result.className = elem[i];

                parent.appendChild(result);
                obj[elem[i]] = document.getElementsByClassName(elem[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    Constructor();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Indentation

I don't understand the indentation. The second line should be indented the same as the first line.

### Multiple `var` declarations

If you declare multiple variables, you can use the `var` keyword only once, and separate variables using the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator), for example:

```
var article = document.getElementsByTagName('article')
   ,obj = {}
   ,wrappers = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

### Semicolons

From [another answer of mine](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/125187/97338):

> You're using many semicolons. JavaScript has a nice feature called
>   automation semicolon insertion, which means you almost don't need to
>   use semicolons at all, with just a few exceptions. From [npm style
>   guide](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/coding-style#semicolons):
>
> > Don't use them [semicolons] except in four situations:
> >
> > - `for (;;)` loops. They're actually required.
> > - null loops like: `while (something) ;` (But you'd better have a good reason for doing that.)
> > - `case 'foo': doSomething(); break`
> > - In front of a leading `(` or `[` at the start of the line. This prevents the expression from being interpreted as a function call or
> >       property access, respectively.
>
> Note that it's only a matter of style. You don't have to follow it if
>   you don't like it, but personally I think that if something is not
>   required, there's no reason to use it.

### Meaningless identifiers

Identifiers like `a1`, `a2`, `a3` doesn't tell much about the purpose of the variable. Try to name them in a way that explain what they are used for.

### Only class names should begin with an uppercase letter

It's recommended to use identifiers starting with an uppercase letter (like `Constructor` in your case) only to declare classes. As you don't use `new` operator when calling that function, I assume it's not a class and therefore should have a name starting with a lowercase letter.

### Use `const` instead of `var` to declare variables that should never be changed

You don't intend to change most of the variables, especially these that refer to the DOM elements. You could use [`const` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) instead of `var` to make sure don't override them accidentally.

### Using variables or functions before they are declared

You're using `create` function before you define it. It is recommended not to use variables or functions before declaring them. Therefore, you should move your `create` function declaration to the top.

### Use `for...of` loop

If you don't need array indexes, you can use the [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop instead of the traditional loop.

Example:

```
for (let element of array) {
  console.log(element)
}
```

### Miscellaneous

I don't see a point in declaring the `set` function and immediately calling it. If you want to create a separate scope, use IIFE, but I don't think you need it here. The same is with the `Constructor` function.

`a1`, `a2`, and `a3` should definitely merged in one array.

Comment: Thats nice but some of those features like const and for of are not so well supported. Do you think the programm is as small as it can get or do you think one can remove more lines of code?

Comment: @Asperger Lack of support in browsers is not an excuse to not use those features. You should use a JavaScript compiler like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/), which compiles code that uses latest ECMAScript features into ECMAScript 5 code.

Comment: I did check and the es5 code generated is so bad compared to what it looks like if I write it from scratch. I mean I know all those functions from java and they are useful but...I mean im not sure if thats good

Comment: @Asperger What do you mean by "bad"? If you mean readability -- that's perfectly fine, the generated code isn't intended to be read by humans. If you're still not convinced, [see who's using Babel](https://babeljs.io/users/).

Comment: you are right but im just trying babel online and it cant convert lets or const, I keep getting errors

Comment: @Asperger It [can](https://goo.gl/Z7pD98). If you have more problems, ask on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Indeed it works. Ive also read on ES7 and its cool as well. I will do that as you said but the naming etc aside for a moment, would you say the code ive wrote is as short as it can get?